# Redmine REST API to get all users

Tags: rest, redmine

I want to retrieve all users from redmine and I use its REST API to get data. it give the  100 users only if I set the limit to 200 also.

Is there any way to retrieve all user from API?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the user you are authenticating as has access to view all the users?

If that is not the issue, then according to [the Redmine REST API documentation](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api#Collection-resources-and-pagination), collections you try and GET from Redmine are not set up generally to return all at once so you will have to use an offset and poll until you have gotten everything.

Or better yet, you can save yourself time and use a library so you don't have to worry about a problem someone has already solved. There is a list of packages in different languages at the bottom of the REST API doc [here](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api#API-Usage-in-various-languagestools).

Answer (score 0):

"...the number of items to be present in the response (default is 25, maximum is 100.."